# How to embed Iframe page on Facebook wall by sharing the URL?

Tags: facebook, iframe, embed

I've been trying to embed an Iframe by sharing a page URL on my Facebook wall. I'm using the Open Graph tags as recommended by Facebook and have read other threads similar to my issue. What I want to achieve is something that others are doing, like Sketchfab, ThingLink, helloeko.com or Kaltura.

The problem I'm having is that instead of the embed page being replaced by an IFRAME when you click on the Facebook post, it's replaced by an HTML5 video tag.

You can test what I'm talking about by sharing a link like this one on a Facebook wall: https://sketchfab.com/models/f3e191a68ec247ff9d4d72d35fd12829. They use this https://sketchfab.com/models/f3e191a68ec247ff9d4d72d35fd12829/embed?autostart=1 as the embed player, which is set by the open graph `og:video:url` tag.

I've done the same with my open graph tags. The Facebook Sharing Debugger is also not returning any errors or warnings and the Open Graph tags are being processed like the examples I mentioned here.

I'm using the following open graph tag also, so the content is not set as a video but instead as text/html:

```
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
```

The only thing I'm not sure how to use is the `og:type` tag. I'm using my Facebook app namespace and the name of an object type I created on the app settings like this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="namespace:object_type">
```

Is there any whitelisting process for the domain I'm trying to embed on Facebook? Can't find anything on the Facebook Developers docs.

Comment: Most of the pages I've seen using iframes are really small businesses, so they might have gone through a submission process to get whitelisted by Facebook.

Comment: Why the downvote? These guys did it: https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed/issues/2250 and a lot others have done it. If I said I read other threads and still posted a question is because I didn't found an answer.

Comment: @CBroe I think this is a legit question, and don't understand how your comment is practical. I have the same question, and if it's not a technical one, perhaps there's a page to submit a proposal for that "partnership" you mention. Also can't understand the downvote...

Comment: There simply isn't a process to apply - Facebook chooses the companies they partner with to try this out.

Comment: Did you get to embed an iframe with Open Graph? I have the same problem as you.